# How to implement Self-host WCF data services (http://localhost:1234/myDataService.svc/...)

Tags: wcf, service, odata, hosting

I have a project that needs to implement WCF data services (OData) to retrieve data from a control system (.NET Framework Application). The WCF data service needs to be hosted by the .NET application (No ASP.NET and NO IIS).

I have seen many WCF Data Service examples recently; they are all hosted by ASP.NET application. I also see the self-host (console application) examples, but it is for WCF Service (not WCF Data Service).

It is possible to have a standalone .NET Applications to host WCF Data Services (http: //localhost:1234/mydataservice.svc/...).

If yes, can someone provide an example?

Comment: Have you tried? Have you been able to self-host a normal WCF service?

Comment: Bounty will go to marc_s after the time limit is up. (For his fantastic answer that saved me tons of time.)  No new answer is needed for the bounty.

Answer (score 28):

I just tried the same thing - and yes, you can host a WCF Data Service in your own assembly - with a few little tricks.

Here's how:

- put your data model (EF Data Model) into its own assembly, let's call it `DataModel`
- create a new class library project (call it `MyDataServiceHost`)
- add a few references:

  - your `DataModel` assembly with the data layer
  - `System.ServiceModel`
  - `System.ServiceModel.Web`
  - `System.Data.Services.Client`
  - `System.Data.Services` - you cannot pick this from the usual `Add Reference` dialog under the .NET category - you need to browse for the assembly file. Find the directory `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` (or `C:\Program Files (x86)\...` on a 64-bit machine) and pick the `System.Data.Services.dll` inside it
- add a new class to that class library and call it e.g. `YourDataService.cs` - it will look something like this:

  ```
  using System.Data.Services;
  using System.Data.Services.Common;

  using DataModel;

  namespace MyDataServiceHost
  {
      public class YourDataService : DataService<YourModelEntities>
      {
          // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
          public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
          {
              // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
              // Examples:
              config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
              config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  You can name the class anything you like, and it has to derive from `DataService<T>` where `T` is the name of your data model; if you're using Entity Framework, it's the name of your object context class - typically something like `(database)Entities` or whatever you picked when you created the EDM
- add another class to your new project, call it `MyDataServiceHost.cs` and it will look something like this:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Data.Services;

  using DataModel;

  namespace MyDataServiceHost
  {
      public class MyDataServiceHost
      {
          public static void LaunchDataService(string baseAddress)
          {
              Uri[] baseAddresses = new Uri[1];
              baseAddresses[0] = new Uri(baseAddress);

              using(DataServiceHost host = new DataServiceHost(typeof(YourDataService), baseAddresses))
              {
                  host.Open();
                  Console.WriteLine("DataService up and running.....");

                  Console.ReadLine();
                  host.Close();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  It instantiates a DataServiceHost, which is derived from WebServiceHost (which in turn is derived from ServiceHost) and it will spin up the WCF Data Service runtime for you.
- now you can start up your WCF Data Service from any app using:

  ```
  MyDataServiceHost.LaunchDataService("http://localhost:4444/YourService");
  ```
- last thing to remember: the app that you use to launch the WCF Data Service **must have** the connection string (the EDM connection string, if you're using Entity Framework) in its app.config (or web.config) in order for this to work!

Comment: If you are watching this question anymore, I followed your answer and got the service running, but when I try to view it in firefox like this: http://localhost:4444/EntitySearch/Countries I get this result: `Resource not found for the segment 'Countries'.`  I double checked my EF code and that class is there ('public ObjectSet<Country> Countries')  Any ideas?

Comment: I had misspelled the 'InitializeService' method name.  (Grr, should have just copied and pasted.)

Comment: I would recommend installing the WCF Data Services Server NuGet package instead of navigating to a local assembly for the reference to System.Data.Services.

Comment: I have 3 projects in VS2012: _WCF Service  Host, ASP.NET WEB API, and WCF DataService_. **Output Path is the same** MyServices\bin\Debug folder for all 3. In development, useful Self Hosting each project. Anyways, **Web.config is common** for all 3. Now, is it possible ***hosting all 3 projects in the same IIS WebSite*** ? ***Conclusion***: _In development, Self Hosting (WCF, WCFDataService, WebAPI). In stagging, Hosting all in the same website._