# Expose a class library as a "WCF Data Service"

Tags: c#, .net, class-library, wcf-data-services

Is it possible to expose a **.NET (class) library** through a **WCF Data Service** ? Makes this scenario sense ? Or is the usage of **pure WCF** the best and only way in this case ?

Background: I have several (old) C# classlibraries (which encapsulate the access to different datasources), which I want to use with **Ajax** and **Silverlight**. I cannot and should not access directy to the datasources and have to use the libraries (because of backward compatibility).

Comment: Marc had a great answer to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042534/how-to-implement-self-host-wcf-data-serivces-http-localhost1234-mydataservice/3042655#3042655). Don't forget to vote him up as it was a great answer and the asker did not even accept it.

Comment: @uhu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042534/how-to-implement-self-host-wcf-data-serivces-http-localhost1234-mydataservic is useful but put your solution

Answer (score 2):

Its worth noting that the XML serialization of objects does not conform to the OO constructs you have in code, ie XML has no notion of inheritence.  If your class library is complicated in this regard, I would advise against it.

Can you not create an independent service that simply uses your class library underneath?  By this I mean creating a new service and service interface, not turning your class library into a service interface.